# Upload image from Silverlight to ASP .net MVC 2.0 Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, silverlight-4.0

I have been trying really hard to Upload a photo from a Silverlight app to ASP .net MVC app.

I simply use WebClient like this in Silverlight :

```
private bool UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
    {
        try
        {
            UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:59933/Admin/Upload");
            ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", fileName);

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                PushData(data, e.Result);
                e.Result.Close();
                data.Close();
            };

            wc.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int byteRead;

        while ((byteRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
        }

    }
```

On the other hand I have created a simple action called Upload like this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
         //Some code here
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't hit the break point in Upload method.

Is this even possible ? The reason why I am using Silverlight is that I want to preview the image before uploading it to server and it is very simple in Silverlight.

I failed to do that in JavaScript and that is why Silverlight might be more useful here.

Comment: look at the http traffic with fiddler and see what happens

Comment: Hugo Estrada, No I haven't :( 
I kind of gave up and used normal html post. If you figure out please let us know too ... ;)

Comment: No ! I no longer use Silverlight. HTML 5 seems to be the future. (I might be wrong)